# Delay in "for" loop in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++)
{
    //code
}
```

and i want to do code every 10 miliseconds.

Thanks for helping

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show what kind of processing this is. Consider using `Task.Delay` API to await instead of normal sleep of thread, and process them manually. Maybe add up the asynchronous code entirely and process it then. Depending on the need, a generator (with `yield`) might also help in this, but this depends on the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use co-routines for this and 1 second is 1000 milliseconds so 1/1000=0.001

```
   IEnumerator Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f);
        print(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Coroutines are calculated in each frame, so if your frame rate is 60, minimum delay is about 16.6 milliseconds. So it doesn't make sense to write a value below this delay in WaitForSeconds.